# Tamil Calender View

Tags: android, calendar, tamil

How can I set the Tamil date in Calendar View, and Tamil font in my application?

Answer (score 4):

You can put Tamil variable name and all other GUI text in Tamil. Just put all this in ***string.xml*** file inside ***values folder***(inside res folder) of your project(Eclipse based project). You have to declare your Tamil language variable here and it work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Google Locales does not support Tamil. So you will need to create your own Locale for Tamil and then use it to create your Calendar. That of course will be extremely tedious.